# A Simple Approach to Create Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I want to display a form like so:

Home Page

```
(1) Make: [_______]    Model: [_______]
(2) Make: [_______]    Model: [_______]
 .
 .
 .
(5) Make: [_______]    Model: [_______]

    [Submit]
```

Response Page

```
(1)  Honda CBR600RR     []  <--- Checkbox
(2)  Lexus LS450
 .
 .
 .
(5)  Ford F150          []

     [Confirm]  [Cancel]
```

First page has no checkbox.  The second page displays checkboxes next to the plain html text retrieved from the input of first page if duplicate entry are found.  I don't need to save any of these data in the database.

I'm not looking for education on forms but rather see how one would approach this problem as my methodology has brought me to a dead end.  Any examples or thorough explanation would greatly enhanced my learning experience.

**Updated:**

forms.py

```
make = forms.CharField ()
model = forms.CharField ()
checkbox = forms.BooleanField (required = False)
```

1. Is it better to include the checkbox field like above or separate it into a separate class?  I think it's better to separate it since the second form doesn't have make/model field and would raise form/validation error.
2. How do I obtain the data from the checkboxes?

Comment: Sounds like a simple `{% if %}` condition in your template. Your formset or form would need to know this "duplicate entries" condition. Lets say you define that functionality in `MyForm.detect_if_duplicate()`.. if so, call it in your template and choose to display a checkbox or not.

Comment: That's what I have as well.  I'm more interested to know how do you obtain the form/formset from the first page and use it on the second form with only the checkboxes.  See my updated commented in the original post.